# How can mako access the object name currently being rendered under Windows

Tags: python, mako

I am new to mako, and have a question about the object model.

We are generating a template file via mako under Windows 7 through the render command, similar to

```
out.write(self.objectname.render(...))
```

within the file being rendered, I want to access the objectname similar to the following pseudo code ...

```
<%namespace name="mapping" module="objtool.mapping" />
<%!
import os
import time
%>\
======================================================
== this file is being rendered from $(object.name)
======================================================
```

Is this even possible?

**Note:**  I can get it to generate output similar to the following

```
this file is being rendered from <mako.template.Template object at 0x02F48990>
```

but I want the actual object name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%namespace name="mapping" module="objtool.mapping" />
<%!
import os
import time
%>\
======================================================
== this file is being rendered from ${os.path.basename(self.name)}
======================================================
```

renders

```
======================================================
== this file is being rendered from poco_custom.cs
======================================================
```